# Cannot convert from 'system.windows.forms.messagebox' to 'string'

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string code = "111-222-73";
        if (Namebox.Text == "" || Codebox.Text == "")

            MessageBox.Show("Please fill a valid login!", MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        else if (Codebox.Text == code)

            MessageBox.Show("Login succesfull!");
        else MessageBox.Show("Wrong code!");


    }
```

This throws an error when I use messageboxIcon but if I don't use it, the messagebox will work. This also applies to the other messageboxes. Can someone tell me why and how I can fix this.

Just switched form vb.net to C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using the correct [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/365dky5y(v=vs.110).aspx) that contains the `MessageBoxIcon` parameter :

```
MessageBox.Show("Please fill a valid login!", "", 
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
```

There is no built-in method in the .NET framework that satisfies your needs but you can create a helper method to do that:

```
public static class MessageBoxHelper
{
    const string _defaultCaption = "Message";
    const MessageBoxButtons _defaultButtons = MessageBoxButtons.OK;

    public static void Show(string message, MessageBoxIcon icon)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(message, _defaultCaption, _defaultButtons, icon);
    }
}
```

Comment: So you need to type it always like that? If you lets say don't mind the messageboxButtons, you can't skip them, you need to write them anyway?

Comment: The second code is more than I can understand. Any explanations and more details?

Comment: @Emre You create a new class (Right Click your project => Add => New Item => Class and name it `MessageBoxHelper.cs` . Then put that code in it. Then instead of your original code, you can use `MessageBoxHelper.Show("Please fill a valid login!", MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);`